# Long time untouched working piece of code, suddenly throwing NullPointerException

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nullpointerexception, firebase-authentication

First things first, I am working on an app, it's main activity being Main2Activity. This activity contains 5 fragments: Home, Settings, New, Notifications and Profile.

Today, without even touching this file's code I started getting this error:

Main2Activity:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.heirup, PID: 15134
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.heirup/com.example.heirup.Main2Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Provided document path must not be null.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Provided document path must not be null.
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:147)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.document(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:103)
        at com.example.heirup.Main2Activity.setNotificationBadge(Main2Activity.java:142)
        at com.example.heirup.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:84)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

This is the method I get the error in:

```
private void setNotificationBadge(Context context) {

        FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        rootRef.collection("users").document(userId).collection("notifications").limit(10).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots) {
                for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : documentSnapshots.getDocuments()) {
                    switch (documentSnapshot.getString("type")) {
                        case "USER_HAS_APPLIED":
                            //irrelevant
                            break;
                        case "ENOUGH_APPLICANTS":
                            //irrelevant
                            break;
                        case "JOB_HAS_STARTED":
                            //irrelevant
                            break;
                        case "JOB_HAS_ENDED":
                            //irrelevant
                            break;
                        case "JOB_HAS_EXPIRED":
                            //irrelevant
                            break;
                    }
                }

                for (Notification notification : notificationsList) {
                    if (!notification.isRead())
                        newNotifications++;
                }

                if (newNotifications > 0 && !checkedNotification) {
                    int menuItemId = navView.getMenu().getItem(3).getItemId();
                    badgeDrawable = navView.getOrCreateBadge(menuItemId);
                    badgeDrawable.setVisible(true);
                    badgeDrawable.setNumber(newNotifications);
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "No document found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Basically, the userId is wrong, but how can it be? I am using `private String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().toString();` to retrieve it and it has always been working..

I did some research and I read some devs had this problem after implementing the Sign out functionality for their apps. Ironically, I really did implement this today in my SettingsFragment:

SettingFragment -> onCreateView()

```
signOut = root.findViewById(R.id.sign_out_btn);
        signOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Can anyone give me any clue? Hope I've been clear enough..

Answer (score 1):

`FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().toString()` does not return a user ID.  It returns the string form of a FirebaseUser object, which is something else entirely.  You will want to use `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()` instead.

Anyway, you should trust the error messages saying that `userId` is null.  It's not wrong about that.  You should debug your code to figure out why it is null.

Comment: Hello! Sorry, I really meant to write .getUid().. anyway, I replaced 
`private String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().toString();`  
with:
`private String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null ? FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() : null;` and debugged it. Only thing I get is "userId = null". Do you have any clue about what might be happening? Can it be a firebase problem?

Comment: Can this error occur if the the account is logged in on another phone? thanks in advance